# Button click not triggered if using bootstrap-table pagination / search

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-table

i'm using wenzhixin `bootstrap-table`, and when i'm loading the page for the first time the button click is triggered, but after paginate through the table (using `bootstrap-table` features, the click is no longer triggered.

a sample code is at: https://jsfiddle.net/eitanmg/gsxb8645/9/

how can i get my button click triggered along with using `bootstrap-table` search / pagination features?

Comment: Because the event is attached only to existing elements. **$("table").on('click', '.done_status', function () {
        alert("hello!");
      });**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click",".done_status",function () {

    alert("hello!");

    });
});
```

You need to bind the click event on the button so it can get detected by DOM.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SmitRaval/gsxb8645/10/)

Comment: Welcome. :) @Eitanmg

Answer (score 1):

I edited your code at jsfiddle it works now with following edit.

```
$("table").on('click', '.done_status',function () {

    alert("hello!");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("table").on('click', '.done_status', function () {
        alert("hello!");
      });
 });
```